# full url is not working in php

Tags: php, csv

For one of the PHP file, I am using one CSV file (file.csv). When I mention the remote URL, it is not working. But when I upload the file to the same directory, then it s working.

**THIS IS WORKING (csv file & php file in same directory)**

```
$handle = fopen("file.csv","r") or die("file dont exist");
    // get data
    while (!feof($handle )){
    // do the stuff
    }
```

**Whereas the remote URL in PHP is not working.**

```
  $handle = fopen("http://www.mywebsite.com/dir/file.csv","r") or die("file dont exist");
    // get data
    while (!feof($handle )){
    // do the stuff
    }
```

Can any body help me in correcting the remote url code please?

Comment: check allow_url_fopen is enabled or not?. http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: in this you can only use this like fopen("dir/file.csv","r")

Comment: how about fopen( __ DIR __ .'/file.csv','r'); ?

Comment: you can give $handle = fopen("/dir/file.csv","r") like this and try.

Comment: you can go php.ini file and check (allow_url_fopen = On) on or off.if that is off please write that there in (allow_url_fopen = On)

Comment: Check the permissions of your remote file